# where to see SQL Server start/stop logs?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql, windows-event-log

I want to know where to see SQL Server start/stop logs for each instances and SQL Server agent/job start/stop logs? I am developing some tools to monitor SQL Server status. I am using SQL Server 2008 Enterprise.

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will find all of the SQL Server activities in the Application Event Log.

You can find this by going to Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Event Viewer > Application, and looking for "MSSQLSERVER", or "MSSQL$INSTANCENAME" in the "Source"